# Mac app Packages - Running pre-installation script issues

Tags: bash, macos, shell, dependencies, package

So I'm using the packages app : http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

Running a pre-installation script for my package that does something simple such as

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir test_folder
exit 0
```

Gives me no issues, creates the folder and installation is successful. (It is a dummy app/package and I am only testing to make sure I can get the installation script to work).

However, when I try to test the actual content I want to install for the user, it says the installation is successful but nothing happens.

```
 #!/bin/sh
export GOPATH=~/gocode
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

go get -d github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd
make && make install

exit 0
```

I'm not sure if my script is incorrect? Do I have to use only native bash commands because I am aware that `go & get` aren't traditional bash commands. I'm really confused because this script works 100% fine when running normally & as admin through the terminal yet gives me issues when using the Packages App.

I'm totally open to achieving this installation a different way (not using Packages or having to do a different script approach).

An alternative I was thinking was to create an Electron Menu Bar app that would run the same script, but I'm not sure if this would work either.

Thank you so much for your help!